# R: Output Function, Wrong Number of Factors in Output

Tags: r, output

I am a complete R noob and I am trying to learn R trough Coursera... I am trying to write a function that calculates mean across 332 different csv files. I am getting the right values, but the output is wrong. I am supposed to get the mean value for one of the factors, but instead I am getting it for both factors.

```
#Assign the directory
pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  
  directory <- list.files(path= "/Users/......./specdata")

  #Create empty vector 
  g <- list()

  #For loop to run through the files and get info and use rbind to create df
  for(i in 1:length(directory)) {

    g[[i]] <- read.csv(directory[i],header=TRUE)

  }

  rbg <- do.call(rbind,g)

  #Subset to get the sulfate/nitrate columns and calcualte the mean
  pollutant <- subset(rbg,ID %in% id ,select = c("sulfate","nitrate"))
  colMeans(pollutant,na.rm = TRUE) 
  
}
```

```
pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate",70:72) 

sulfate   nitrate 
0.9501894 1.7060474
```

So far, so good...the values are correct. However, the problem is that since I am passing "sulfate" into the pollutantmean, then I should get the sulfate mean only. However, instead I am getting both. Why is that? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: (i) The parameter directory in your function is pretty useless, since the function replace the parameter in the first line; (ii) the pollutant parameter is similarly useless in your function as it is similarly replaced by the identically named `pollutant` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your code properly, you have hard-coded `c("sulfate", "nitrate")` into your function. The variables which you are passing to the function need not be hard-coded that way.

Change your function to the following:

```
#Assign the directory
pollutantmean <- function (directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  
  directory_files <- list.files(path = directory)

  #Create empty vector 
  g <- list()

  #For loop to run through the files and get info and use rbind to create df
  for(i in 1:length(directory_files)) {

    g[[i]] <- read.csv(directory_files[i],header=TRUE)

  }

  rbg <- do.call(rbind,g)

  #Subset to get the sulfate/nitrate columns and calcualte the mean
  pollutant_subset <- subset(rbg,ID %in% id ,select = pollutant)
  colMeans(pollutant_subset,na.rm = TRUE) 
  
}
```

```
pollutantmean("/Users/......./specdata","sulfate",70:72) 

sulfate
0.9501894
```

You should get the proper results now.